# Simulate AI clicking in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, tic-tac-toe

I made a game of tic tac toe in Android Studios. I also made an AI that the player can play against, however the AI doesn't need to "click" because it can just set the values of the specific row and column to its value (X or 0). Is there a way to simulate a click from the AI?

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_00"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_01"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_02"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_10"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_11"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_12"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_20"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_21"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_22"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

My layout is pretty simple and in my player vs player mode, the clicks just look like:

```
if(!((Button) v).getText().toString().equals("")){return;}
if(player1turn){ ((Button) v).setText("X"); 
        }else{ ((Button) v).setText("O"); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [`Button.performClick()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#performClick())

> Call this view's OnClickListener, if it is defined. Performs all
>   normal actions associated with clicking: reporting accessibility
>   event, playing a sound, etc.